# The data points in the beeswarm plot produced using swarmplot are not getting scattered?

Tags: python

In the below code, when plotting a beeswarm plot using a swarmplot function, I am observing that the data points are not getting scattered in data set 2. But if I change the data set to data set 1, the data points are getting scattered very well. I need that even with the data set 2, the points should be scattered very well. I have tried even by changing the scatter size but to no result. Can somebody help in figuring this out ??

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn

# Making beeswarm plot
A=np.array([0.02,0.02,0.02,0.04,0.04,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8])  # data set 1
#A=np.array([20,20,20,20,50,50,50,35,35,35,45,45,58,58,58,58,69,69,69,63,63,63,36,63,77,78,80,80,80,80])    # data set 2
data = A

x_labels = " Depth (Microns)"
y_labels = " Diameter (Microns)"

seaborn.set(color_codes=True)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))
axes = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect=1)
 
# add title to plot
plt.title("Beeswarm Distribution Plots of Swept Droplet Diameters")
 
# plot data on swarmplot
seaborn.swarmplot(data=data, color="blue", size=8)
 
# y-axis label
axes.set(ylabel=y_labels)
axes.set(xlabel=x_labels)
axes.set_xticklabels(['200'])

plt.show()
```

I am attaching the images of the beeswarm plots produced using the data sets 1 and data sets 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el3dp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M75xm.png)

Comment: Drop the `fig.add_subplot` line and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `aspect=1` flag for `axes` so that line reads

```py
axes = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
```

Alternatively, you can avoid the subplot jargon altogether unless you intend on adding more subplots to this figure.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn

# Making beeswarm plot
# A=np.array([0.02,0.02,0.02,0.04,0.04,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8])  # data set 1
A=np.array([20,20,20,20,50,50,50,35,35,35,45,45,58,58,58,58,69,69,69,63,63,63,36,63,77,78,80,80,80,80])    # data set 2
data = A

x_labels = " Depth (Microns)"
y_labels = " Diameter (Microns)"

seaborn.set(color_codes=True)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 16))
 
# add title to plot
plt.title("Beeswarm Distribution Plots of Swept Droplet Diameters")
 
# plot data on swarmplot
seaborn.swarmplot(data=data, color="blue", size=8)
 
# y-axis label
plt.ylabel(y_labels)
plt.xlabel(x_labels)
plt.xticks(labels=['200'], ticks=[0])

plt.show()
```